NextJs useState fails when running in docker
The code bellow when i run locally it works fine. When i push this code to a docker container i get the following error:


... function Viewer() {

  const [isMuted, setIsMuted] = useState<boolean>(true);

  async function toggleMute() {
    await updateState();
    console.log("toggleMute isMuted",toggleMute); // Assuming this.state.firstName is part of your component state
  }
  
  async function updateState() {
    try {
      console.log("isMuted before setIsMuted: ", isMuted);
      await setIsMuted(!isMuted);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }
  

  useEffect(() => {

    console.log("isMuted: ", isMuted);

}, [isMuted]);

 return (
    <>
  <IconButton aria-label="audio" onClick={toggleMute}>
              {isMuted ? <UnmuteIcon /> : <MuteIcon />}
            </IconButton>

       <Component componentProperty={property} muted={isMuted} />
    </>
  );```

Trying to update muted stated on button click and pass it to the inner component


Have you attempted to execute the command 'npm run build' locally?

Hi, 1st check what version of node do you use on your local machine, and which version in docker. 2nd use same package-lock.json or yarn.lock from local environment when building docker image.

I'm doing that my docker file has # Stage 1: install dependencies
FROM base AS deps
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
COPY .npmrc ./ COPY --from=builder /app/.next ./.next
COPY --from=builder /app/pages ./pages
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/package-lock.json ./
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./
COPY --from=builder /app/.next/static ./.next/static
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
